# Prove that the given matrix has only one eigenvalue at 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix, arising out of a PDE, with sparsity pattern as shown in attached pic, the values not shown are all 0s (Note that [1 -2 1] structure for all rows except for rows 1, 17, 33, 49). All row sums (sum of all elements in a given row) is 0. The matrix is real and NOT symmetric. Plus, using Gershgorin theorem, it is known that all eigenvalues are in the left half plane.

I am trying to prove that this matrix has **only one** eigenvalue at 0 (at least one eigenvalue at 0 is easily proven). A stronger result would be to prove that all  eigenvalues real and simple, i.e. distinct (something similar is already known for tridiagonal matrices, as shown [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379579900399) ). Till now, my approach is this: since it is close enough to a tridiagonal matrix, I am trying to transform it to a tridiagonal matrix using similarity transformation. But, it hasn't worked out so far.

Also, are there matrices in the literature with similar structure?

Please let me know if the question seems incomplete and you need more information.Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: The sparsity pattern of matrix. the values not shown are all zeros.]

Comment: You mention that the eigenvalue at $0$ is easy to see: is the corresponding eigenvector all ones?  In any case, if eigenvector $w$ is known, a naive approach is that there would be a second eigenvalue $0$ iff some vector $v$ orthogonal to $w$ satisfies $Av = cw$ for some scalar $c$ (possibly $0$, but typically not).  Equivalently $A^2 v = 0$.

Comment: @ErickWong: Yes, the corresponding eigenvector is all 1s. If I understand correctly, you are saying that if I am able to prove that there is no vector $v$ orthogonal to $w$ (the vector of all ones), such that $Av= cw$, then there is only one eigenvalue at 0? May I know what theorem or result are you using here?
Also, for any $v\perp w$, we must have $\sum v_k = 0$, where $v=[v_1\, v_2 \, \ldots \, v_n]$. For any such vector, $Av\neq 0$ by construction, right?

Comment: I'm not sure how you know that $Av \ne 0$ by construction (maybe you already know that the nullity of $A$ is $1$, it isn't obvious to me by inspection).  If $0$ has geometric multiplicity $>1$ then by definition there is an $Av=0$ with $v \perp w$.  Otherwise if $0$ has algebraic multiplicity $>1$ then $A$ has a nilpotent Jordan block of size $>1$, and squaring this block shows that $A^2$ will have nullity $>1$.  Thus there will be a non-trivial solution to $A^2 v = 0$ with $v \perp w$, and since the only solutions to $Av=0$ are $cw$ this means $Av = cw$.

Comment: It may be helpful to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector, which gives a geometric way to interpret repeated eigenvalues even when there's only one eigenvector.  You're trying to rule out a generalized eigenvector of rank 2 for the eigenvalue 0.